# Iterators for nested templates

Tags: c++, templates, iterator

What is the general rule for creating iterators of nested templates? For example, how would you create an iterator for the following templates:

```
map<int, pair<string, int> > M;
map<map<int, string>, map<string, pair<int, int> > N;
```

Answer (score 4):

The rule is adding a `::iterator` if the container offers it.

Answer (score 2):

Just like iterators to any kind of container:

```
map<int, pair<string,int>>::iterator it1; // or const_iterator
map<map<int,string>, map<string, pair<int,int>>::iterator it2; // or const_iterator
```

Answer (score 2):

just add `::iterator`

```
map<int, pair<string,int>>::iterator
map<map<int,string>, map<string, pair<int,int>>::iterator
```

Answer (score 2):

Standard C++ containers define a type alias called `iterator` and one called `const_iterator` that you can refer to.

For instance, if your type is:

```
map<int, pair<string,int>>
```

Then you can get the type of an iterator to its elements by doing:

```
map<int, pair<string,int>>::iterator
//                        ^^^^^^^^^^
```

Or, if you need a constant iterator:

```
map<int, pair<string,int>>::const_iterator
//                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

However, in C++11 you often do not need to do this, because `auto` allows you to let the compiler deduce the type of the iterator:

```
map<int, pair<string,int>> m;
// Fill in the map...
auto i = m.begin();
```

The last line of the above snippet is equivalent to:

```
map<int, pair<string,int>>::iterator i = m.begin();
```